# WCF on IIS 7 Errors

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, iis-7, basichttpbinding

I am currently making a WCF service and while I was developing the service acted like it should (Using Visual Studio Web Expres). I have a silverlight application who is consuming the service.

I wrote the WCF service in a class Library and is implemented by a ASP.NET Web Application. While I was using the Visual Studio ASP.NET Development Server the service was happy and gave me everything I asked for.

Now I implemented the service on an IIS 7 Server. And the service doesnt return what I ask for anymore. Instead in Chrome I get the following message:
[image: The error through Chrome]

But If I surf to the service url then the service say's it is ready to rock and roll:
[image: if I surf to the service]

As you can see in the Error I get from Chrome is that the text the service returns is the Source code from that "surf to" page.

My Web.config service model:

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basicHttpBinding_OnlineCreatorServiceContract" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                   openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                   maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None" />
          </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="OnlineCreatorServiceBehavior"
          name="OnlineCreator.ServiceLibrary.OrderDataService">
          <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_OnlineCreatorServiceContract"
            name="basicHttpBinding" contract="OnlineCreator.ServiceLibrary.IOrderDataService" />
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
      </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="OnlineCreator.Web.OnlineCreatorServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                    <enableWebScript />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="OnlineCreatorServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

And my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://subdomain.domain.com/mapWithServiceInIt/OnlineCreatorService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="OnlineCreatorService.IOrderDataService" name="basicHttpBinding" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Because my service is on a subdomain I have used to following ClientAccessPolicy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*"> 
        <domain uri="*"/> 
      </allow-from> 
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

As you can see this can't be the problem, but for completeness sake I have putted it here.

This is my first WCF service and it worked perfectly till I putted it on the IIS server. Does anyone has a clue why I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you enable [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and see if there is any more error info?

Comment: Do you have a clientaccesspolicy on the root of your subdomain, or only the main domain? Run up Fiddler2 and see what it is requesting.

Comment: I have (just to be sure) a client acces one on the root of the domain,  one on the root of the sub domain and one in the folder where the silverlight app (and service) is located.

Comment: Take Silverlight out of the equation for starters. Try making the service calls with SoapUI. You may be playing with your server at the moment as I got a "Document Moved" response. Suggest you delete your log link ASAP.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by take silverlight out of the equation? The whole point for the service is to run for silverlight.

Comment: first off please see this about the configuration of maxBufferPoolSize http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713180/how-do-you-configure-leasetimeout-setting-with-nettcpbinding/6720923#6720923 - Second look at the html being returned from this call - i usually get this when the url is wrong or make sure the app is calling the correct address

Comment: @jon the html that is returned is the same html as the source of the second image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I have dug deeper in WCF and IIS I found out that you need to activate WCF on the server. And that is quite the process. To do it right I cleared my current site on IIS to have a fresh start and then followed to following pages to get the WCF to work:

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751527.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blambert/archive/2009/02/13/enable-iis.aspx
http://edinkapic.blogspot.com/2009/02/talking-to-wcf-service-from-silverlight.html

I made a very simpel HelloWorld service to test everything and as soon as it all worked I ported it to my service. That first gave me an exception. But that was soon fixed because the connection strings weren't set right.